# Rederive the Maclaurin series for the function $f(z)=\cos(z)$.

Tags: complex-analysis

**Question:** Rederive the Maclaurin series $$\cos(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \dfrac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!}=1-\dfrac{z^2}{2!}+\dfrac{z^4}{4!}-\cdots$$ whenever $|z|<\infty$ for the function $f(z)=\cos(z)$ by

$1.$ using the definition $$\cos(z)=\dfrac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$$ and appealing to the Maclaurin series $$e^z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{z^n}{n!}$$ whenever $|z|<\infty$ for $e^z$.

$2.$ showing that $$f^{(2n)}(0)=(-1)^n \text{ and } f^{(2n+1)}(0)=0$$ where $n=0,1,2,\dots$.

**Proof:** We want to show $\cos(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \dfrac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!}$ whenever $|z|<\infty$. Recall that $\cos(z)=\dfrac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$ and $e^z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{z^n}{n!}$ whenever $|z|<\infty$ . Then

\begin{align*}
\cos(z)&=\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{iz}+e^{-iz}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(iz)^n}{n!}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-iz)^n}{n!}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{i^n z^n}{n!}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n i^n z^n}{n!}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{i^n z^n(1+(-1)^n)}{n!}.
\end{align*}

My question is how to I use (2) to the problem?

Comment: $f$ is analytic so $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$. Which means that $f^{(n)}(0) = n! a_n$ and so $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty   \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} z^n$.

Comment: Where does this fact come from?

Comment: I dont see a reason to use 2). You just need to use the fact that $1+(-1)^n$ is zero for odd $n$ and 2 for even $n$. You also need to work out $i^n$. Which alternates between i,-1,-i,1. But you can use 2) for direct derivation of the taylor series for the evaluation at z=0.

Comment: @MrYouMath thats how I feel but I am just following the directions.

Comment: I think they mean. Derive it with two methods. Firat by the first hint and then by using the second hint.

Comment: @MrYouMath oh that makes sense. Thank you for noticing that.

Answer (score 2):

If $n$ is even, then $\frac{1+(-1)^n}{2}=1$ and $i^n=e^{i\pi n/2}=(-1)^{n/2}$.

If $n$ is odd, then $\frac{1+(-1)^n}{2}=0$.

Therefore, we see that

$$\begin{align}
\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{i^nz^n(1+(-1)^n)}{n!}&\overbrace{=}^{n=2m}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{i^{2m}z^{2m}(1+(-1)^{2m})}{2\,(2m)!}\\\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^mz^{2m}}{(2m)!}
\end{align}$$

as expected!